# Why does Sarada Uchiha wear glasses?

Tags: naruto, boruto

In the anime, it was stated that Uchihas have the best eyes in terms of **sight** and visual prowess. If Uchihas have the best sight then why does Sarada Uchiha wear glasses?

I know there was the whole 'who is Sarada's mom' arc but

> it was revealed that Sakura is Sarada's mom, not Karin

so then why does she have glasses? Even though her glasses are a gift, we know that she legitimately needs them (she doesn't wear them for style) and neither of her parents wear glasses.

I haven't read the manga so if there are any canon reasons as to why Sarada has glasses can you please give me the source?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are actually multiple reasons for this.

According to Manga, Sarada's eye condition was explained as an illness as a child, post which she had to wear glasses. I can't find the exact panel, but Narutopedia kind of corroborates this. She has perfect vision while activating the Sharingan, while her vision is no better or worse

> During her father's absence from the village while gathering information on Kaguya Ōtsutsuki, she became ill with a high fever and afterwards, began wearing glasses, which unknown to her were a gift from Karin. 
> [Sarada Uchiha: Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sarada_Uchiha)

Sharingan enhances her vision, but only while activated and the normal vision is just like everyone else.

However, the real reason is out-of-universe. It was **Design Aesthetic**, plain and simple. Kishimoto felt like giving her glasses, so he gave them to her.

> **Interviewer:** How is Sarada? [Or what about Sarada? T/N: In the context of design.]
>   **Kishimoto:** Rather than cuteness, I wanted to project a slightly dark but strong hearted sense to Sarada. In my head, she is like a girl version of Sasuke. However, as it would be scary to have a Sasuke-like girl, I gave Sarada elements of Sakura as well. Although spectacled people are commonly given the image of “cute without glasses”, *in Sarada’s case I aimed to make her cute even with her glasses on*. Her clothes have a sense of Sakura, don’t they? 
> [Kishimoto Interview Excerpt](http://chennyyeo.tumblr.com/post/117315142456/source-ch1p-of-narutoforum-and-purely)

Answer (score -2):

I guess another valid argument for Sarada wearing glasses is because of Sasuke going blind after excessive use of his Sharingan. Obviously, his eyes are fine now because he implanted Itachi's eye to him giving him the eternal MS, but without that, he would be blind. So those genes of Sasuke actually being blind were given to Sarada, having bad vision at an early age.